# Apache Spark and MongoDB integration using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pymongo

i have a problem working with apache spark and mongodb using the pymongo library. Actually, i am processing thousands of records and for each record, i need to read its corresponding data from the database, update certain info and save it back to the database. Due to the reads and writes, i choosed to use Pymongo instead of using Spark-Mongo Connector which apparently isnt well suited for this task. Unfortunately however, when performing writes, mongodb always returns write successful but when i check the database, some updates where not performed. After debugging for over a week, i realized by setting the server to a single core processor, all writes were successful and written in the database but the application has become tremendously slow. 
I would like to know if anyone knows how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks but i have solved it. Actually, due to the large number of reads and writes and considering the fact that i had nested documents, MongoDB would succeed in operations such as $push and $inc but not on operations such as $set. So what i did was to redesign my DB schema such that i had a maximum of 2 levels of nesting and it now works well. LESSON:: Create as few nested documments as possible in MongoDB when dealing with very fast reads and writes